# Remove a particular day from dataframe column (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

This is my dataframe (time is an index):

```
                     price
time
2015-11-07 00:00:00   180.250000
2015-11-07 00:15:00   176.350000
2015-11-07 00:30:00   177.533333
2015-11-08 00:45:00   180.216667
```

I want to remove all entries of the day '2015-11-07' so I tried:

```
remove = df.loc['2015-11-07]
df.drop(remove)
```

But I receive this error `labels ['price'] not contained in axis`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need remove by `index` of `DataFrame` called `remove`:

```
remove = df.loc['2015-11-07']
print (remove)
                          price
time                           
2015-11-07 00:00:00  180.250000
2015-11-07 00:15:00  176.350000
2015-11-07 00:30:00  177.533333

print (df.drop(remove.index))
                          price
time                           
2015-11-08 00:45:00  180.216667
```

Another solution:

```
idx = df.index.difference(df.loc['2015-11-07'].index)
print (idx)
DatetimeIndex(['2015-11-08 00:45:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='time', freq=None)

print (df.loc[idx])
                          price
time                           
2015-11-08 00:45:00  180.216667
```